# Website is ready, how the hell do I make it responsive?

Tags: responsive-design

As mentioned on the title, Iv'e just finished making a static website, using - CSS/JQUERY/SLICK/JQUERY/BOOTSTRAP.

And I have no idea what to do or where to start in order to make it responsive, tried google but still feeling confused not sure about where to start...

As for now minimizing the page seems to do nothing but cutting the area been minimized.
Changing the view to phone-view on chrome devtool causing the website to look the same, just extremely small which means you can't really read text or anything without zooming in.

any ideas or guidelines of how to start?... feeling lost which is weird cuz am feeling pretty comfortable with the method mentioned above.

Thanks alot for reading!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not usually giving shitty comment. But I have to say it. Mobile first.

Comment: Anyway if you're using bootstrap, read the doc. You have to understand what's a row, what's a col and how is that amazing for making responsive websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking the mobile site after doing the standard one is not a good idea. But you are already at the end of that road and there is no going back now.

Responsiveness mostly works on the CSS side. You cambine media queries to specify which CSS should be used for each screen size, but it also has to do with your content structure. As mentioned in the comments, using rows and columns when designing your site helps doing the mobile site a lot.

I suggest you start reading this if you haven't: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

And go through each section under the Responsive Web Design section. It should give you a good introduction to help you get started.